# Strange behaviour with Javascript Array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This may turn out to be a stupid mistake on my part, but my JSON object array is behaving unexpectedly.

The JSON object `insertDoc` has `startDate` and `endDate` fields and i'm trying to create a new object for each day in between -

```
            var insertDocs = [];
            var finalDate = insertDoc.endDate;

                while (insertDoc.startDate <= finalDate) {
                    insertDoc.endDate =  insertDoc.startDate;
                    console.log('doc is ' + JSON.stringify(insertDoc));
                    insertDocs.push(insertDoc);
                    insertDoc.startDate = new Date(moment(insertDoc.startDate).add(1, 'days')); 
                }

            ...

            for (var i = 0; i < insertDocs.length; i++) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(insertDocs[i]));
            }
```

Here's the browser output -

```
doc is {"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
doc is {"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
doc is {"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
doc is {"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-04T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-04T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
doc is {"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
```

Output of stringify - same doc printed 5 times

```
{"description":"testtask","endDate":"2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z","startDate":"2019-04-06T00:00:00.000Z","status":"OPEN"}
```

So it seems each object is different and correctly printed but the array just seems to be 5 of the same object. The date values are different too

Am i missing something here?

Comment: You're pushing `insertDoc` every time. You need to clone the object if you want separate objects.

Comment: `insertDocs.push(insertDoc);
                    insertDoc.startDate = new Date(moment(insertDoc.startDate).add(1, 'days'));`  here sequence is wrong assignment should come before pushing it.

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed this concept was unclear to me. I was able to use `insertDocs.push(Object.assign({}, insertDoc))` to get this working